# React: onClick I want to download the csv files, with queryparam and if download fails due to wrong params want to display popup message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, onclick

*onClick I want to download the csv files, with queryparam and if download fails due to wrong params want to display popup message*

Here is my onClick doSubmit method,

```
 const doSubmit = () => {
    let timeZoneoffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
    let location = `${apiEndpoint}/export-device-data?fromDate=${fromDateTime}&toDate=${toDateTime}&userId=${values.userId}&deviceTypeId=${deviceId}&timeZoneoffset=${timeZoneoffset}`;
    window.open(location, '_blank');
  };
```

with the above code I am able to download the csv file if I pass the correct params values. But when I pass the incorrect params values getting error object in new tab:

```
{"status":false,"responseCode":400,"message":"Invalid Request"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make a "GET" AJAX call and only if you get 200 as the HTTP status code then you should open the popup and load the page. And if you get > 400 in HTTP status code then show a popup.

```
fetch("linkedin.com")
.then(data => {
if(data.status < 400)
//popup
else
//display error message
enter code here
})
```

But with this you ll end up sending 2 requests to load the page.

Comment: hi @Vishal, thanks for your suggestion but here I need to take the user's input like fromDateTime, userId, deviceId, etc.. and then pass those as param. So I can required data as csv fromat.